# Why this sql is correct? (sql injection)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

What does it mean?

```
SELECT * from users where password = ''*'';
```

if I check this in mysql workbench I get only **one line**, although I have lot of users in table.

What exactly does this select?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting question. Let's see what `''*''` does.

```
mysql> select ''*'';
+-------+
| ''*'' |
+-------+
|     0 |
+-------+
```

Let's create some users:

```
mysql> select * from users;
+------+-------+
| id   | name  |
+------+-------+
|    1 | joe   |
|    2 | moe   |
|    3 | shmoe |
|    4 | 4four |
+------+-------+
```

And test our query:

```
mysql> select * from users where name = ''*'';
+------+-------+
| id   | name  |
+------+-------+
|    1 | joe   |
|    2 | moe   |
|    3 | shmoe |
+------+-------+
```

Interestingly enough, user 4 was not selected! But let's try this way:

```
mysql> select * from users where name = 4;
+------+-------+
| id   | name  |
+------+-------+
|    4 | 4four |
+------+-------+
```

So, what can we deduct from this?

1. `''*''` somehow means 0 (I am not that fluent in mysql string operators, so let's take it as a fact);
2. MySQL, apparently, does type conversions in this case. So if you query a varchar column against an integer, it tries to convert those strings to ints and see if it's a match;
3. You have only one row whose `password` begins with 0 or non-digit.

Comment: This quite familiar operator has nothing to do with *string* operations ;)

Comment: Look at it closely, it's really simple. You know this operator perfectly well :)

Comment: But indeed this case is wonderful, gonna add it my collection.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: you mean that this is number multiplication operator and mysql casts both sides to numbers? I'd expect an error here, if _both_ operands are not numbers :)

Comment: MySQL can cast anything )

Answer (score 5):

1. You can always use an *expression* in SQL. Like SELECT 5-4 AS one and get 1. So you can tell that here is an expression.
2. MySQL is a loosely typed language, so it can multiply strings. Casting them to numbers. And get you zero as a result of `'' * ''`
3. When comparing a string with a number, MySQL casts both to a number. So 0 = 'name' condition will get you true

Answer (score 4):

The `''*''` is a multiplication: its two arguments (empty strings) are converted to numericals (i.e. 0) and the result is 0. Then the left side of the equation is also converted to a number, which will sometimes be zero (when the password cannot be evaluated to a non-zero number), sometimes not.

It is a bit obscure, and you could ask yourself whether this was intended in your case or an accidental behaviour, while the actual intention was to test for `'*'`. A user with bad intentions might have entered `'*'` as a password hoping you were not protected against SQL injection in order to get into the system without a valid password.

Comment: Testing for _equality_ to `'*'` is a bit pointless for such attack, don't you agree? Unless you manage to sneak `LIKE` in as well. But maybe it was a next step.

Comment: The attack, if indeed this is what happened, would be just the entering of `'*'` as password. The rest of the SQL would have been in the (bad) program code already.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.